# Is the Dassault "ministop" related to the Dunlop Maxaret ABS?

Tags: aviation-history, landing-gear, aircraft-subsystem

Dassault fighters e.g. Ourargan and Mystere had Anti-lock devices called "Ministop" on main landing gear brakes.
Anybody has a picture / drawing / detailed description ?
Is the Ministop related to the Dunlop Maxaret ABS ?

Comment: It has been built by Messier. On page 141 and next of [this book](http://www.eurosae.com/pdf/comaero/Veaux_Trains_d_atterrissage.pdf) in French, dedicated to landing gears, the author compares Messier and Dunlop systems: "*Ministop consisting of an accelerometer driven in rotation by the wheel and controlling an electrical contact releasing or cutting hydraulic pressure when the deceleration exceeded a defined value (on/off system). Used on Mystère IV, Super Mystère B2, Mirage III, Mirage IV. In 1962 the Ministop was the subject of a testing campaign On Mirage IIIC n°01 at Brétigny CEV*"

Answer (score 2):

This [1953 issue of Flight International](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1953/1953%20-%200927.html?search=Messier%20Ministop) mentions the Messier Ministop, it seems it was shown publicly for the first time at the Salon de Paris, July 1953:

> A particularly interesting development was the new anti-skid device which is being marketed under the name of Ministop. The device consists of an accelerometer—a free mass rotating with the wheel—together with a centrifugal governor and an associated electrical circuit. The general principle of operation is very similar to that of both the Dunlop Maxaret and the Westinghouse Decelostat ...

From that wording I'd say Ministop is unlikely to be a license-built version of Maxaret.